# Disabling a button inside a gridview using jquery

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

I have a gridview and on the 6th column there is a link button. I want to enable/disable the link button according to the value of 7th column.... Iam using the following code. but it wont work...

```
$('#<%=xgvVisitersRegister .ClientID%> tr').each(function() {
        if ($(this).find('td:eq(7)').text() != "") {
            $(this).find('td:eq(6)').attr("disabled", true);
            }
            else {
               $(this).find('td:eq(6)').attr("disabled", false);
            }
        });
```

Pls Help me to correct it..
thanks in advance...

Comment: `$(this).find('td:eq(6) :input')` is the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try disabling the link button inside the td instead of disabling the td.

Something like

```
$(this).find('td:eq(6) a').attr("disabled", true);
```

Find the anchor tag inside the td.

But the better method will be check this in the server side itself.

You can hook the [**RowDataBound**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event and inside that you can check for this.

Answer (score 1):

Why you want to use Jquery to perform this task while you can achieve this easily by using Gridview's RowDataBound event.
Try this one:

```
Protected Sub gvSample_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvSample.RowDataBound

    Dim objDRV As DataRowView = CType(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim btnApprove As LinkButton = CType(e.Row.FindControl("btnApprove"), LinkButton)

        If Not objDRV("Column7") Is Nothing AndAlso objDRV("Column7").ToString() <> "" Then
            btnApprove.Enabled = False
        Else
            btnApprove.Enabled = True
        End If
    End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Why jQuery?
Did you try [LinkButton.Enabled Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.enabled%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)?

Comment: once you go jQuery you never go back :)